# Tensorflow, python: Using CSV Data for Logistic Regression

Tags: python, tensorflow

How can I train a logistic regression model with csv data instead of images using tensorflow? All the examples that I've seen online uses images instead of csv data, and I currently have no clue how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

There are some tutorials online available have examples of using csv data. The same kind of processes can be applied to a logistic regression model instead of just a linear one. For example:

https://aqibsaeed.github.io/2016-07-07-TensorflowLR/ - A look at reading house price data from CSV

Or from Tensorflow - https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data#file_formats

Once the data is read in it can be manipulated and trained on as normal.